# How to ignore unclosed tags in XML or HTML?

Tags: html, xml, haskell, html-parsing, xml-conduit

I'm writing a parser in Haskell for the site using the packages Text.XML and Text.XML.Cursor.

There are unclosed tags and get an error:

> Main.hs: Error parsing XML file dat.html: 29:1-29:8: Expected end
>   element for: Name {nameLocalName = "br", nameNamespace = Nothing,
>   namePrefix = Nothing}, but received: EventEndElement (Name
>   {nameLocalName = "body", nameNamespace = Nothing, namePrefix =
>   Nothing})

What to do? How to ignore such tags?

Comment: Try  [`tagsoup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text object with unclosed tags is not [***well-formed***](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) and ***is therefore not XML.***

So, forget about using any XML libraries, parsers, or tools.  They are, by definition and design, not able to help you.

You have two options.  Either,

1. Repair the textual object to be well-formed by closing the unclosed
   tags.  You might do this manually or try using [TIDY](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), or
2. Define a new data format that allows unclosed tags, and write a
   parser from the ground up for it.

Comment: I understand that the unclosed tags do not correspond to the format of XML, but it is a third-party site and modify the data can not.
Using a library obtained tagsoup disassemble site without errors, but it is not convenient to work with. I would like to find a solution to Text.XML.

Comment: Third party doesn't matter.  Inconvenient doesn't matter.  **It's not XML, so you can't expect to use an XML library.**  I'm trying to help you by explaining your options, but if you're holding out for an XML library to help you parse non-XML data, neither I nor anyone else can help you.  Good luck.