# Stax does not ready characters like "&ldquo;"

Tags: java, xml, stax, sgml, sgmlreader

I'm doing a Sgml parse with Stax. The Sgml contains characters like "“ ”" and many others that is not replaced setting the UTF-8.
The parse breaks and throws the following exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[6,22]
Message: The entity "lpar" was referenced, but not declared.
```

I have one another problem, I have some tags without a close tag, for exemple `<coolspan>` without a and tag . This break the parse.

I was thinking about create a method to replace all special characters and validate tags without a end tag. 
Someone already passed by a problem like this, and could show me a way to  follow?

Comment: I don't think you will succeed to parse a document that does not follow XML rules with an XML parser.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577021/how-to-ignore-unclosed-tags-in-xml-or-html

Comment: Those entities have to be declared, and tags have to be closed, or you don't have well-formed XML.