# How can i access this soap xml response

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

Hi im already out of idea tried namespace and other functions of simpleXMLELEment php class but no luck here is the xml `

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId CorrelationId="3d0d561e-4c03-428a-b14a-399eca0acdfd" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">50b0d0e5-5187-4991-9725-181d1a452d9c</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <CruiseLinesResult xmlns="http://tourico.com/webservices/">
         <CruiseLinesList>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1213019" CruiseLineName="Azamara Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="130" Name="Azamara Journey"/>
                  <Ship ID="131" Name="Azamara Quest"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="11493" CruiseLineName="Carnival Cruise Line">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="162" Name="Carnival Breeze"/>
                  <Ship ID="1" Name="Carnival Conquest"/>
                  <Ship ID="129" Name="Carnival Dream"/>
                  <Ship ID="13" Name="Carnival Ecstasy"/>
                  <Ship ID="14" Name="Carnival Elation"/>
                  <Ship ID="15" Name="Carnival Fantasy"/>
                  <Ship ID="16" Name="Carnival Fascination"/>
                  <Ship ID="89" Name="Carnival Freedom"/>
                  <Ship ID="3" Name="Carnival Glory"/>
                  <Ship ID="18" Name="Carnival Imagination"/>
                  <Ship ID="19" Name="Carnival Inspiration"/>
                  <Ship ID="4" Name="Carnival Legend"/>
                  <Ship ID="5" Name="Carnival Liberty"/>
                  <Ship ID="146" Name="Carnival Magic"/>
                  <Ship ID="6" Name="Carnival Miracle"/>
                  <Ship ID="20" Name="Carnival Paradise"/>
                  <Ship ID="7" Name="Carnival Pride"/>
                  <Ship ID="21" Name="Carnival Sensation"/>
                  <Ship ID="117" Name="Carnival Splendor"/>
                  <Ship ID="185" Name="Carnival Sunshine"/>
                  <Ship ID="9" Name="Carnival Triumph"/>
                  <Ship ID="10" Name="Carnival Valor"/>
                  <Ship ID="11" Name="Carnival Victory"/>
                  <Ship ID="281" Name="Carnival Vista"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1030965" CruiseLineName="Celebrity Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="25" Name="Celebrity Century"/>
                  <Ship ID="26" Name="Celebrity Constellation"/>
                  <Ship ID="152" Name="Celebrity Eclipse"/>
                  <Ship ID="121" Name="Celebrity Equinox"/>
                  <Ship ID="43" Name="Celebrity Infinity"/>
                  <Ship ID="50" Name="Celebrity Millennium"/>
                  <Ship ID="161" Name="Celebrity Reflection"/>
                  <Ship ID="151" Name="Celebrity Silhouette"/>
                  <Ship ID="120" Name="Celebrity Solstice"/>
                  <Ship ID="76" Name="Celebrity Summit"/>
                  <Ship ID="85" Name="Celebrity Xpedition"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1030966" CruiseLineName="Costa Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="29" Name="Costa Classica"/>
                  <Ship ID="147" Name="Costa Deliziosa"/>
                  <Ship ID="192" Name="Costa Diadema"/>
                  <Ship ID="184" Name="Costa Fascinosa"/>
                  <Ship ID="182" Name="Costa Favolosa"/>
                  <Ship ID="31" Name="Costa Fortuna"/>
                  <Ship ID="126" Name="Costa Luminosa"/>
                  <Ship ID="32" Name="Costa Magica"/>
                  <Ship ID="34" Name="Costa Mediterranea"/>
                  <Ship ID="194" Name="Costa neoRiviera"/>
                  <Ship ID="193" Name="Costa neoRomantica"/>
                  <Ship ID="127" Name="Costa Pacifica"/>
                  <Ship ID="94" Name="Costa Serena"/>
                  <Ship ID="36" Name="Costa Victoria"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1201987" CruiseLineName="Cunard Line Ltd.">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="99" Name="Queen Elizabeth"/>
                  <Ship ID="118" Name="Queen Mary 2"/>
                  <Ship ID="128" Name="Queen Victoria"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1223492" CruiseLineName="Disney Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="150" Name="Disney Dream"/>
                  <Ship ID="160" Name="Disney Fantasy"/>
                  <Ship ID="148" Name="Disney Magic"/>
                  <Ship ID="149" Name="Disney Wonder"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1030967" CruiseLineName="Holland America Line">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="23" Name="Amsterdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="116" Name="Eurodam"/>
                  <Ship ID="46" Name="Maasdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="189" Name="Nieuw Amsterdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="53" Name="Noordam"/>
                  <Ship ID="63" Name="Oosterdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="67" Name="Prinsendam"/>
                  <Ship ID="70" Name="Rotterdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="71" Name="Ryndam"/>
                  <Ship ID="75" Name="Statendam"/>
                  <Ship ID="77" Name="Veendam"/>
                  <Ship ID="79" Name="Volendam"/>
                  <Ship ID="81" Name="Westerdam"/>
                  <Ship ID="86" Name="Zaandam"/>
                  <Ship ID="88" Name="Zuiderdam"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1201988" CruiseLineName="MSC Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="135" Name="MSC Armonia"/>
                  <Ship ID="183" Name="MSC Divina"/>
                  <Ship ID="136" Name="MSC Fantasia"/>
                  <Ship ID="137" Name="MSC Lirica"/>
                  <Ship ID="138" Name="MSC Magnifica"/>
                  <Ship ID="140" Name="MSC Musica"/>
                  <Ship ID="141" Name="MSC Opera"/>
                  <Ship ID="145" Name="MSC Orchestra"/>
                  <Ship ID="134" Name="MSC Poesia"/>
                  <Ship ID="190" Name="MSC Preziosa"/>
                  <Ship ID="144" Name="MSC Sinfonia"/>
                  <Ship ID="143" Name="MSC Splendida"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1030968" CruiseLineName="Norwegian Cruise Line">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="181" Name="Norwegian Breakaway"/>
                  <Ship ID="55" Name="Norwegian Dawn"/>
                  <Ship ID="132" Name="Norwegian Epic"/>
                  <Ship ID="195" Name="Norwegian Escape"/>
                  <Ship ID="115" Name="Norwegian Gem"/>
                  <Ship ID="186" Name="Norwegian Getaway"/>
                  <Ship ID="66" Name="Norwegian Jade"/>
                  <Ship ID="57" Name="Norwegian Jewel"/>
                  <Ship ID="95" Name="Norwegian Pearl"/>
                  <Ship ID="64" Name="Norwegian Sky"/>
                  <Ship ID="59" Name="Norwegian Spirit"/>
                  <Ship ID="60" Name="Norwegian Star"/>
                  <Ship ID="61" Name="Norwegian Sun"/>
                  <Ship ID="65" Name="Pride of America"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1262572" CruiseLineName="Oceania Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="176" Name="Insignia"/>
                  <Ship ID="179" Name="Marina"/>
                  <Ship ID="177" Name="Nautica"/>
                  <Ship ID="178" Name="Regatta"/>
                  <Ship ID="180" Name="Riviera"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1201986" CruiseLineName="Princess Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="98" Name="Caribbean Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="100" Name="Coral Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="105" Name="Crown Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="101" Name="Dawn Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="108" Name="Diamond Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="109" Name="Emerald Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="104" Name="Golden Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="96" Name="Grand Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="106" Name="Island Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="159" Name="Ocean Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="110" Name="Pacific Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="197" Name="Regal Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="112" Name="Royal Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="125" Name="Ruby Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="113" Name="Sapphire Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="103" Name="Sea Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="107" Name="Star Princess"/>
                  <Ship ID="102" Name="Sun Princess"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1030969" CruiseLineName="Royal Caribbean Int’l">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="22" Name="Adventure of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="142" Name="Allure of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="191" Name="Anthem of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="24" Name="Brilliance of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="38" Name="Enchantment of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="39" Name="Explorer of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="40" Name="Freedom of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="42" Name="Grandeur of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="119" Name="Independence of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="44" Name="Jewel of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="45" Name="Legend of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="90" Name="Liberty of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="47" Name="Majesty of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="48" Name="Mariner of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="52" Name="Navigator of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="124" Name="Oasis of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="188" Name="Quantum of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="68" Name="Radiance of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="69" Name="Rhapsody of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="72" Name="Serenade of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="74" Name="Splendour of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="78" Name="Vision of the Seas"/>
                  <Ship ID="80" Name="Voyager of the Seas"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1260326" CruiseLineName="Seabourn">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="167" Name="Seabourn Legend"/>
                  <Ship ID="168" Name="Seabourn Odyssey"/>
                  <Ship ID="170" Name="Seabourn Quest"/>
                  <Ship ID="169" Name="Seabourn Sojourn"/>
                  <Ship ID="166" Name="Seabourn Spirit"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
            <CruiseLine CruiseLineId="1260327" CruiseLineName="Silversea Cruises">
               <ShipList>
                  <Ship ID="171" Name="Silver Cloud"/>
                  <Ship ID="174" Name="Silver Shadow"/>
                  <Ship ID="175" Name="Silver Spirit"/>
                  <Ship ID="173" Name="Silver Whisper"/>
                  <Ship ID="172" Name="Silver Wind"/>
               </ShipList>
            </CruiseLine>
         </CruiseLinesList>
      </CruiseLinesResult>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Im tyring to access it using PHP but no luck its saying that trying to access and non-object property here is my current code

```
` $xml =  simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->children('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')->Body->children('http://tourico.com/webservices')->CruiseLinesResult->CruiseLinesList->CruiseLine[0]->Shiplist->Ship[0];`
```

Comment: Your xml is not well formatted

Comment: that is the file im getting, so what will i do now to make it well formatted then ?

Comment: Please someone help me on this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577021/how-to-ignore-unclosed-tags-in-xml-or-html

Comment: https://eval.in/603829 It's code to start